# Completely remove grub dual boot screen and boot directly to ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have installed both Windows 10 and Ubuntu in my laptop. I can select boot option in my UEFI settings. If I select windows boot loader my system will directly boot into Windows but if I select Linux, my system shows grub bootloader. This is very annoying. I want to directly boot into Ubuntu without any delay.

I have tried some time out and other settings in grub config file so now I couldn't see grub screen. But now also grub loads in parallel and it automatically boots Ubuntu, so it restarts again in Ubuntu. I want to remove this time consuming process.

Can I directly boot to Ubuntu without grub boot loader?